# how to correctly use >>= to replace the do and <- in this code?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a question that goes on how to work with monads. I have the following code:

```
import System.Random
import Data.Random.Normal
import Graphics.EasyPlot
import Data.List
import Data.Function 

random' mean randomGen = zip x y 
    where                
       x = normals' (mean, 0.2) randomGen :: [Float]
       y = normals' (mean, 0.2) randomGen :: [Float]

randomW1 randomGen = [[x,y] | (x,y) <- random' 1.0 randomGen]

main = do  
    randomGen <- getStdGen
    let w1 = take 50 (randomW1 randomGen)
    print w1
```

and it works fine. However, I think its limiting to bind the output of `getStdGen` outside of `randomW1`, and thought I could be able to bind the `getStdGen` more directly to `randomW1` by writing

```
w1 = take 50 (randomW1 =<< getStdGen)
```

I believe I have utilised the `>>=` or `=<<` to "pipe" monadic structures together, and replacing the use of `do` and `<-`. When I am doing as I suggest I discover that it

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
Expected type: [StdGen]
  Actual type: IO StdGen
```

is there a way to use `>>=` to replace the `do` and `<-` in this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
main = do  
    w1 <- getStdGen >>= (return . take 50 . randomW1)
    print w1
```

(parentheses not actually needed)

Personally, I dislike the style above, since `>>= (return . f)` can be achieved with `fmap f` in a simpler way, as follows:

```
main = do  
    w1 <- (take 50 . randomW1) `fmap` getStdGen
    -- or: w1 <- take 50 . randomW1 <$> getStdGen
    print w1
```

Removing the last `<-`, we get:

```
main = print . take 50 . randomW1 =<< getStdGen
```

---

Here's a more systematic approach to derive the last one, step by step. Start from the beginning:

```
main = do  
    randomGen <- getStdGen
    let w1 = take 50 (randomW1 randomGen)
    print w1
```

Inline `w1`:

```
main = do  
    randomGen <- getStdGen
    print (take 50 (randomW1 randomGen))
```

Desugar `do x <- m ; e` into `m >>= \x -> e`. This is how the `do` syntax  is defined.

```
main = getStdGen >>= \randomGen -> print (take 50 (randomW1 randomGen))
```

Use composition for the last lambda:

```
main = getStdGen >>= print . take 50 . randomW1
```

Comment: just dropping this note here that some people like `<$>` for `\`fmap\``.

Comment: @JustinL. Indeed, I was going to use that! But I stepped back since it requires to `import Control.Applicative`.

Comment: @chi In GHC 7.10 that import isn't necessary anymore. By the way, a fourth way of writing it is `print =<< take 50 . randomW1 <$> getStdGen`, which maps quite neatly to the different parts of the original do-block.

Comment: I am getting Precedence parsing error cannot mix ‘.’ [infixr 9] and ‘fmap’ [infixl 9] in the same infix expression from main =  do 
 w1 <- take 50 . randomW1 `fmap` getStdGen
 print w1

Comment: @hotGopher Right. Added a few parentheses.